# Symbolic links and 7zip

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, 7-zip

I'm trying to compress a folder into a .7z archive. This folder contains symbolic links to some other stuff outside the folder (both directories and files).

Apparently 7zip just archives the link itself which is not what I intended. Is there a way to tell 7zip that I want it to archive the stuff that it links to, not the link itself? (That is if there is a symlink name `foo` which points to `C:\stuff\foo`, I want it to include the `C:\stuff\foo` directory in the archive in place of foo, not a 0-byte symlink.))

Is there any reasonable workaround apart from adding the files and folders in question? There are about 10,000 files referenced via symlinks so adding them all individually would take hours… Maybe there's a program that creates a staging folder with the real files in it and then passes that to 7zip. Or just an archiver that does handle symlinks better.

I'm running Windows Vista. All the links are symbolic links (eg created with `mklink link target` and `mklink /D link target`).

EDIT:

`dir` command output for a smaller test directory:

```
C:\...>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 0A3D-CD6E

 Directory of C:\...

09/04/2010  18:12    <DIR>          .
09/04/2010  18:12    <DIR>          ..
09/04/2010  18:10               975 real file.txt
09/04/2010  18:11    <SYMLINK>      test file.txt [..\test file.txt]
               2 File(s)            975 bytes
               4 Dir(s)   5,214,355,456 bytes free
```

Creating a 7z archive of that with 7zip results in `real file.txt` being included, but `test file.txt` is added as a 0 byte file, although the file linked to does exist and is 50KB.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Doesnt the "windows" tag suggest that im using, well windows...

Comment: Ok, What version of windows are you using?

Comment: @Fire Lancer: Generally, it's a good idea to repeat any information from the tags in the text. Easier to read, and not everyone looks at he tags (as they're at the bottom). Plus, the tags can be prone to misunderstandings. E.g., I might be on Linux but want to interoperate with Windows, so I tag my question "windows".

Comment: @Fire Lancer: Please check and specify whether the "symbolic links" you describe are really *symbolic links*, or rather *junction points* (different, but related). That makes a difference (see hova's answer).

Comment: They are symbolic links (supported in windows as of NT 6.0), not junction points.

Comment: Output the "dir" command for the directory, because I don't believe you.  I've tested it and it *works*.

Comment: Happy now that there really not junctions (which would give <JUNCTION>), although tbh id argue that 7zip should really support all link types in a reasonable manner, ie including external files into the archive.

Comment: Well, it would appear that 7z archives <SYMLINKD> and <JUNCTION> directories but not <SYMLINK> files, so i guess if you can sneak all your files into a directory and symlink that it would work

Comment: Another mitigation can be to create `.tar.xz` or `.wim.xz` instead of `.7z`, because
symlinks to files are properly added into `.tar`/`.wim` archives (as opposed
to `.7z`). For these, content vs symlink archival can be controlled by the `-snl` switch.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Apparently 7zip just archives the link
>   it's self which is not what I
>   intended. Is there a way to tell 7zip
>   that I want it to archive the stuff
>   that it links too, not the link its
>   self

No, apparently not (unfortunately). There is actually a bug report on 7zip requesting this:
http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2846755&group_id=14481&atid=114481
but it was opened in August 2009 and not touched since :-/.

> Failing that is there any reasonable
>   around it, apart from adding the files
>   and folders in question? Including the
>   stuff through the symlink there's like
>   10 000 files, the large proportion of
>   which are via symlinks so adding them
>   all individually would take hours...

Well, if you have enough space (and time), you can make copy of the folder, replacing the symlinks with their targets. You can e.g. use [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) and its switch `/sl`:

> /sl Copies the symbolic link instead
>   of the target

---

**Note:**
Just to avoid confusion, note that the Linux build of [p7zip](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) (a port of 7zip) also has a binary `7z` which *does* support archiving the file a symbolic link points to (switch `-l`). However, 7zip on Windows does not have this switch.

Comment: Because this is the approved answer, want to point that actual 7zip does it by `-l` switcher. zip and gzip does too with their specific commands.

Comment: @erm3nda where do you see this switch? Please, provide the reference.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/7z
There is a option l, and there is also a switch with the same letter.

I've note that this option is not present at the Windows version of the software.

Comment: @erm3nda: Yes, but that is p7zip, a port of 7zip. Thanks for pointing it out; I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you too. Can't believe that Windows is missing this feature. Even if the symlinks on Windows are quite diferent, don't figure out why is hard to make it work.

Comment: Correction, I can believe, but don't like :D

Comment: @m3nda Weirdly in the newer (?) version shipped with Ubuntu 21.04, this switcher is lost. Version: 7-Zip [64] 16.02, p7zip Version 16.02.

Comment: And why not piping the robocopy output to the 7zip input stream?, so you don't have to temp store the data with linked files.

Comment: As of 2022, on Debian the -l switch works as expected, but is not documented anywhere...

Answer (score 11):

As of 2019, 7-Zip has resolved this issue in Windows. The latest version has a checkbox to include symlinks in TAR and WIM archives and it works great!

[image: Store Symbolic Links in TAR]

[image: Store Symbolic Links in WIM]

Comment: Where is this checkbox? It's not showing up in the archive window. What version is this for?

Comment: @Starwarswii I have included screenshots showing the checkboxes. This is version 19.00 (x64).

Comment: Even on v19.00 I do not have this option, even though it is a NTFS drive.

Comment: @BramVanroy - are you sure you selected TAR or WIM for the archive format? It is showing up for me even on 7-Zip 15.05

Comment: tar and wim do copy the files / directories, but don't compress. So after tar-ing, you can then .zip or .7z the tar file. Turns out a bit easier than doing a copy to a new target first.

Comment: Note: in order to get the target file / directory - not the link - you need to CLEAR the check box, not tick it.

Comment: it works, but if you use junction file, 7zip will convert to symbolic file.

Comment: Upvoted for the hidden trick, but given that the wim format supports compression (with MSFT tools) this isn't much of a feature in 7zip, especially since it can't create wim.7z files in one pass, so you need a temp file and what not.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Vista and above, remove the symlinks and replace them with mklinks

```
mklink /D Directory FullPathToRealDirectory
```

Note that mklink is pretty powerful and can include links to network shares and the like.

Since there seems to be some confusion on this, allow me to clarify.   I'm assuming the OP is actually talking about Junctions as illustrated here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point.  Mklink does *not make junctions*.  It makes TRUE symbolic links and I tried it myself and 7zip respects them perfectly.   Also, you need to be administrator to create mklink symbolic links.

```
 Directory of C:\temp\t

04/08/2010  04:50 PM    <DIR>          .
04/08/2010  04:50 PM    <DIR>          ..
04/08/2010  04:31 PM    <SYMLINKD>     GB [c:\users\testuser]    <-- created by mklink
04/08/2010  04:50 PM    <JUNCTION>     GB2 [\??\c:\users\testuser] <-- created by junction
04/08/2010  04:29 PM                 8 test.txt
```

7zip will archive GB, but it will NOT archive GB2.  EDIT: Actually further testing shows that 7zip WILL archive both directories using version 4.65.  So I have no clue what the problem is.

Comment: Given all the orig symlinks were made with the Microsoft API's and mklik in the first place, what does this solve apart from remake the same thing?

Comment: -1 How does that solve the problem? You just describe how to create symbolic links.

Comment: @hova: Yes, that is all true (though MS usually only calls the symbolic links "symbolic links"; junctions are never referred to as "symbolic links"). But how does this relate to the question?

Comment: 7zip archives SYMLINKD (mklink) directories!

Comment: @hova: OK, *now* I see (downvote removed). If 7zip can actually archive targets of symbolic links, this makes sense.

Comment: Note however that OP clarified that the links are already symbolic links, so this will not help unfortunately.

Comment: I just did some testing with 7zip v15.14 (64 bit) on Windows 7, and it seems that 7zip now follows directory symlinks but only stores an empty file for file symlinks -- which is not very useful.

Comment: I made one zip and then wrote files from another location over it. Favouring the larger files. Obviously not ideal but it's what MacGyver would've done and it worked.