# Zip with symlink in it?

Tags: zip

I read that zip files can contain symlinks. I want to test what our software library does with such symlinks and whether this is a security concern for our server.

Therefore I'm in need of such a zip file. However, I'm not able to create one. Does anyone have a sample file or at least can tell me how to create one myself?

I've got Winzip, WinRAR and 7zip and I didn't manage to create such a zip with either one :-(

Comment: already answered over here https://superuser.com/questions/128969/symbolic-links-and-7zip

Answer (score 3):

For 7z, `WIM` and `TAR` can contain symbolic links. I don't think `ZIP` can contain symbolic links in windows.

[image: WIM 7z]

Comment: According to https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/73718/how-zip-symlink-works they can?!

Comment: That works on linux where links are just files. However on NTFS, they are 0 byte files and the link information is not stored in the file itself.